# Pressure dependency of the end node correction in a double-ended resonator

Tags: acoustics, resonance

I have an acoustic resonator which is tube-shaped and open on both sides. The open ends of the tube open into a buffer volume. In the picture below I visualized my assumption.

[image: Acoustic tube resonator with open ends and buffer volumes]

Measuring the resonance frequency of my resonator with ambient pressure in the whole cell (buffers + resonator) I had a deviation from the theoretical resonance frequency given by

$$f_{res} = \frac{c}{2L}$$

with $c$ being the speed of sound and L being the resonator length. The deviation was assigned to the well-known effect of **end node correction**. This end node correction replaces the length of the resonator $L$ with its effective length. At lower pressures, I measured a shift of the resonance frequency towards lower frequencies giving rise to the assumption that node shifting into the buffer volume is enhanced by lower ambient pressure. However, I couldn't find a mathematical expression explaining this behavior, nor am I sure this is the reason for the shift. Could someone help me out here?

EDIT: "high" ambient pressure is actually 1030 mbar. The word "high" was a little misleading. "low" ambient pressure means pressure between 1000 - 300 mbar.

Comment: Are the "buffer volumes" big enough to be considered infinite in comparison with the tube?

Comment: Also, is the change in pressure large enough to make the speed of sound change?

Comment: The length of resonator and buffer is quite the same. Both are 30mm in length. the diameter of the buffer voule is approx. 3x the diameter of the resonator.

Comment: I was a little bit unclear regarding the pressure. The red pressure wave is created not at high, but at "normal" ambient pressure =1030mbar and by lowering the pressure inside the cell down to 300 mbar the resonance frequency decreaased. I don't think, that the speed of sound changes, but the effective length seems to increase. In my opinion this happens due to a stronger influence of the end node correction.